# Android custom ListView with custom header?

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I have a `listview` with custom items with `checkbox` and I also have a custom header for `listview` with select all `checkbox` field.Now I whenever I have select header `checkbox` than i want all `checkbox` in `listview` is selected like all select and all unselect on header checkbox selection.

Here is code for adapter and click event on checkbox.

**HEADER CODE :**

```
ftoPfmsDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bene_upload_details);
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.upload_grid_header, null);
        ftoPfmsDetails.addHeaderView(header);
```

**ADAPTER CODE :**

```
final FtoDetailsAdapter adapter = new FtoDetailsAdapter(BeneficiaryDataForUpload.this, gridUploadData, 2, chkAll);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ftoPfmsDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**HEADER CHECKBOX ALL SELECT CODE**

```
 final CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox) header.findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
chkAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    ftoPfmsDetails.setItemChecked(i, true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: try this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-checkall-and-uncheckall-for-a-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

To utilise setItemChecked your ListView has to be setup to handle it.
See this quote from the docs:

> The is only valid if the choice mode has been set to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE or CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE.
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int, boolean)

So you can follow this method and set your ListView to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE and make your row checkable.

OR instead of setting an `OnClickListener` on your headers checkbox, set an `OnCheckedChangedListener` and add a flag to your adapter and set it in the listener eg. `FtoDetailsAdapter.checkAll = isChecked;`. Then after setting that flag you just have to notify the adapter that the data set has changed and update the lists checkboxes accordingly in the adapters `getView` method.

Comment: thanks u...yoooo... done...found solution..after doing this on onclick..

                    boolean chk = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
    
                    for (int i = 0; i < gridUploadData.size(); i++) {
                        ftoPfmsDetails.setItemChecked(i, chk);
                        gridUploadData.get(i)
                                .setSelected(chk);
                     
                    }
                    
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
                }